# what is the best way to create mobile website and desktop website?

Tags: php, html, web, web-deployment

I am going to develop a hotel reservation website. i am also new in website designing. my client need both mobile, tablet and desktop website.

what is the best way for create mobile, tablet and desktop website separate or in one design like fluid gird format?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. But look up "**responsive web design**" on Google.. I'm sure there are many helpful tutorials to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently mobile browsers can show very well a normal website, even if it is not a mobile version. You can start building the "desktop" website and later make some adjustments (with css media queries) to show better a mobile version. Keep in mind that mobile version must be simpler and easy to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new in website designing then try to learn twitter's `bootstrap`. It will make your job easy in designing responsive websites.